# Custom Workflow Activity - Solution does not exist

Tags: workflow, solution-package

I've created a custom Workflow Activity, per the instructions at http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Sandboxed-workflow-activities-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx.

I created my custom action, and I deployed it to my local development instance of Sharepoint 2010.  I then opened a site in Sharepoint designer and saw the custom activity.  I used the custom activity to build a workflow, which I attached to a custom content type on my site.  I then started the workflow on an item of that content type, but I got an error.

In the Sharepoint UI, I see "Error Occurred" for the workflow status.

In the Logs, I see this:  the specified solution does not exist.  Here is the full error log:

---

> 02/25/2011 12:47:06.60    w3wp.exe (0x1EB8)
>     0x17B4  SharePoint Foundation           Workflow Infrastructure
>     88xr    Unexpected  WinWF Internal Error, terminating workflow Id#
>   43953536-9664-4c90-bf6f-0afd40d71128  6a94b7d5-c4a3-42b0-96de-d22dd9c3da17
>
> 02/25/2011 12:47:06.60    w3wp.exe (0x1EB8)
>     0x17B4  SharePoint Foundation           Workflow Infrastructure
>     98d4    Unexpected  System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot execute the
>   sandboxed code workflow action "ID352".   The specified solution
>   "65282f1d-8cda-4617-9c4d-4bf34c8da539" does not exist.      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.SPUserCodeWorkflowActivity.ExecuteUserCode()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.SPUserCodeWorkflowActivity.System.Workflow
>     .ComponentModel.IActivityEventListener<System.Workflow.ComponentModel
>      .ActivityExecutionStatusChangedEventArgs>
>      .OnEvent(Object sender,
>   ActivityExecutionStatusChangedEventArgs e)      at
>   System.Workflow.ComponentModel.ActivityExecutorDelegateInfo`1.ActivityExecutorDelegateOperation
>      .Run(IWorkflowCoreRuntime workflowCoreRuntime)
>   at
>   System.Workflow.Runtime.Scheduler.Run()   6a94b7d5-c4a3-42b0-96de-d22dd9c3da17

---

The Solution ID listed is indeed the solution ID for my solution - when I right-click on the package folder in my project and click 'View Designer', that solution ID shows up in the properties window under 'Solution Id'.

And this solution is deployed farm wide - I went to Central Administration, and it shows up.  If I retract from visual studio, my solution disappears from Central Admin, and if I Deploy from Visual Studio, it appears in Central Admin.

So why can't Workflow find my solution?

Here is my Elements.xml:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
    <WorkflowActions>
      <Action
        Name="Disseminate Work Folder"
        Category="Analysis"
        Assembly="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
        ClassName="Dissemination_Activity.Dissemination"
        FunctionName="DisseminateWorkFolder"
        AppliesTo="all"
        UsesCurrentItem="true" 
        SandboxedFunction="true">
        <RuleDesigner Sentence="Disseminate %1 to %2">
          <FieldBind DesignerType="FieldNames" Id="1" Text="files" Field="FileList" />
          <FieldBind DesignerType="ListNames" Id="2" Text="document library" Field="ResultsDocumentLibrary" />
        </RuleDesigner>
        <Parameters>
          <Parameter Name="FileList" Type="System.String, mscorlib" Direction="In" DesignerType="FieldNames" Description="The list of files to disseminated" />
          <Parameter Name="ResultsDocumentLibrary" Type="System.String, mscorlib" Direction="In" DesignerType="ListNames" Description="This is where the resulting zip file will be placed" />
          <Parameter Name="__Context" Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.WorkflowContext, Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions" Direction="In" DesignerType="Hide" />
        </Parameters>
      </Action>

    </WorkflowActions>
</Elements>
```

Comment: Is there any more information you can add here about things you've tried or if you've been able to find a solution? Does it work in other environments>

Answer (score 1):

It looks like that manifest file (Elements.xml) has incorrect DesignerType for copyRoleAssignments in FieldBind and Parameter elements in specified example http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Sandboxed-workflow-activities-in-SharePoint-2010.aspx.

I suppose it should be DesignerType="Dropdown" for FieldBind and Parameter elements.

Below is correct version for RuleDesigner and Parameters

```
<RuleDesigner Sentence="Breaks role inheritance on the item (copy current roles: %1)">
<FieldBind Field="copyRoleAssignments" Text="Copy Roles" Id="1" DesignerType="Dropdown"/>
</RuleDesigner>
<Parameters>
<Parameter Name="__Context" Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.WorkflowContext,Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions" Direction="In" DesignerType="Hide" />
<Parameter Name="copyRoleAssignments" Type="System.Boolean, mscorlib" DesignerType="Dropdown" Direction="In" Description="Copy roles" />
<Parameter Name="Result" Type="System.String, mscorlib" Direction="Out" DesignerType="ParameterNames" Description="Result of activity"/>
</Parameters>
```

In your case please make sure that parameter `__Context`  is presented in Parameters element

```
  <Parameter Name="__Context"
                     Type="Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions.WorkflowContext, Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowActions"
                           Direction="In"
                           DesignerType="Hide"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `SandboxedFunction="false"` in 'Elements.xml' and then redeploy your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I spent the better part of a week trying to figure this out and finally came up with a solution for the same error.

The reason in my case was that I was referencing the `ClassName` with the namespace as well since it appears that way in many examples I've found. I can't see your code but I had something like this using your definition

```
namespace Dissemination_Activity
{
    class Dissemination
    {
        public Hashtable DisseminateWorkFolder(SPUserCodeWorkflowContext context, string FileList, string ResultsDocumentLibrary)
        {
            // etc
        }
    }
}
```

I was referencing this with

```
ClassName="Dissemination_Activity.Dissemination"
```

However, I had to drop the namespace in this line and change it to

```
ClassName="Dissemination"
```

Now it works.

Hopefully this helps someone.